# Image metadata Keywords not recognized by Windows XP

Tags: wpf, image, metadata, wic

I am using WIC (Windows Imaging Component) in my WPF application to read/write image metadata. Everything works perfect except for keywords not being recognized by Windows XP in the Summary properties tab.

Vista & 7 recognizes it properly in the Tags property.

I would greatly appreciate any pointers..

Murugesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question to MSDN WIC forum and got an answer to my question. I am sharing the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/b1ca325d-b5a0-4a72-a11e-8ce2fd8e4efe) here so it might help someone having the same problem in future.

Murugesh.